# soap client не может подконнектиться

Tags: php, soap

Все работало, пока в один прекрасный момент не решили поменять все коннекты, в итоге 1с-ник настроил связь через другой порт и дал ссылку вида (раньше работало без порта, подразумеваю по стандартному):

> http://00.000.000.000:55/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl
>   (не пишите, типо, как оно работает с 0-лями... Это замененные данные)

И теперь постоянно ошибка. Может кто-то что-то подскажет...
Вот кусок кода:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://00.000.000.167/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl',
        array('login'        => 'user',
            'password'       => 'pass',
            'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
            'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, //WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY, //, WSDL_CACHE_NONE, WSDL_CACHE_DISK or WSDL_CACHE_BOTH
            'exceptions'     => true,
            'trace'          => 1));
} catch(SoapFault $e) {
    trigger_error('Ошибка подключения или внутренняя ошибка сервера. Не удалось связаться с базой 1С.', E_ERROR);
    var_dump($e);
}
```

P.S. Если вбить ссылку просто в браузер то запросит логин и пасс, и введя их отдаст информацию...

Comment: Что за ошибка-то? (содержимое SoapFault $e покажите).

Comment: Для заменённых данных есть домены example, для примеров IP - целых три подсети 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24, 203.0.113.0/24 по rfc5737. Пока что не очевидно, что вы корректно указали порт. Сам wsdl тоже закрыт basic auth авторизацией?

Comment: Порт именно в адресной строке как дали так и записал

Comment: http://example:55/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как корректно его нужно указать...

Comment: ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(186) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://exaple:55/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://exaple:55/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl" " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL"

Answer (score 1):

Клиент не может загрузить `wsdl`. Я так понимаю, что сам `wsdl` у вас тоже закрыт за `http basic` авторизацией.

`SoapClient` [не пытается](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27777) использовать параметры login и password для получения `wsdl` и предполагает, что документ доступен по прямой ссылке без авторизации. Но стандартную запись авторизации непосредственно в URL [понимает и может использовать](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#88902):

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://' . urlencode($login) . ':' . urlencode($password) 
      . '@00.000.000.167/Trade/ws/SiteExchange?wsdl',
    array('login'        => $login,
        'password'       => $pass,
        'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
        'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions'     => true,
        'trace'          => 1));
```

Comment: Пробовал используя порт и не используя, все-равно ошибка

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос, логин с большой буквы, это может влиять?

Comment: Порт у вас нестандартный для http - поэтому порт надо указывать обязательно. Попробуйте с той машины, где у вас клиент запускается запросить wsdl чем-нибудь более общительным. Например, консольным curl.

Comment: Сегодня выявились новые обстоятельства! Оказывается коннект с локалки (Ubuntu, lamp) проходит, все быстро, вся нужная инфа отображается. А с хостинга нет. Может подкинете мыслей??

Comment: firewall (на обоих хостах), ACL веб-сервера, ACL в реализации SOAP-сервера. Куча их. Та хоть косяк маршрутизации. Загрузите wsdl чем-нибудь более разговорчивым, так видно будет есть ли tcp соединение, что отвечает на http запрос.

Comment: Есть файл коннекта, с локалки - все нормально, с другого хостинга - тоже все нормально, а на хосте на котором лежит - ошибка. Что от поддержки хоста требовать вот не могу придумать

Comment: Что непонятно в предложении загрузить wsdl именно с проблемного хоста каким-нибудь другим http клиентом, который умеет говорить что-нибудь более подробное чем "failed to load external entity"? curl, wget, да хоть netcat'ом ручками HTTP запрос вписать.

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);`
Что ещё добавить что бы видеть ошибки, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: cURL Error: Failed to connect to 00.000.000.167 port 55: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах soap добавил **'verifyhost' => false** и все пошло!